# Plotting an array as a point in 2D space in Python?

Tags: mapping, dimensionality-reduction, som, tsne, runumap

I have some lists with a large length and I want to plot them in 2D (like a scatter plot). The thing is, I need to maintain their topology / preserve their distance when I do this mapping.
If the distance(A,B) > distance(A,C), it should stay that way.
What can I use to do that in Python?

UMAP was suggested to me but I am not sure if that's what I'm looking for. The preserving distance part is important. Or maybe Self Organizing Maps? But it needs to be trained and optimized as far as I know. I was looking for the best non-complicated way to do this.

Comment: Starting with a SOM in default parameters could help you. Umap or t-SNE as well, even though they are harder to interpret